# Face detection of a face with mask

Tags: opencv, face-detection

I would like to know if there is a pre-trained model to detect a face wearing a mask? What can I do to detect face with the mask ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there are and there are many

https://github.com/l2-labs/wearmask-model

[image]

https://github.com/AIZOOTech/FaceMaskDetection

https://github.com/topics/face-mask-detection

[image]